# d3.js - labeling ticks with linear x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, axis

i am plotting multiple line graphs. i am not using a .csv file, instead i have a two-dimensional array.

every line has an own array that contains its values. i have another array for the x-axis which contains the indices of the values from the value arrays.

right now i am using a liear x-axis and a linear y-axis. 
my problem is that i can determine how many thicks the x-axis should have but not the labeling.

the labeling is always the index from the x-axis array on that position.
i want to have a different number there.
do i have to use an ordeal x-axis?

thank you!

Comment: Technically speaking, in a line chart the measurement points are ordered by the value of x axis (traditionally). So, yes, you need to have a time scale or an ordinal scale in the x axis, unless you are making something like a connected scatterplot and calling it a "line graph" incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for the answer!
does my array for the x-axis need to contain as much elements as the line graph arrays values?

Comment: Yes, because they come as pairs: for each x value you have an y value. Again, I'm talking about a typical line chart.